# AngularJS Directives: Storing Scripts and Stylesheets

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, stylesheet

Is it possible to place all of your stylesheets and scripts into a directive?  Looking to cleanup my index file and place them into a couple directives like so

```
    <head>
        <ng-stylesheets></ng-stylesheets>   
        <ng-scripts></ng-scripts>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a test</p>
    </body>
```

Is this unnecessary?  I prefer the cleanliness of a directive rather than a giant block of stylesheet references.  I am using Angular 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's a good idea, how would you dynamically read (to later write) the path of your scripts with angularJS? And even if you achieve this, you need to add angular.js and your directive to index.html file anyway.

I suggest you, tu use a grunt/gulp/webpack task to dynamically add all yours scripts and stylesheets to your index.html file on build time. Or even better, you can concatenate all yours script in a single one, using another task.